# telnet to mysql, which timeout is used?

Tags: mysql, timeout

When I telnet to a MySQL DB, the connection gets dropped quickly. Should I increase the interactive_timeout or the wait_timeout?

(Background: trying to keep SSH port forwarding alive on 3306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not using telnet to connect to database servers.

Recommend using ServerAliveInterval (man 8 ssh_config) to keep your connection alive rather than a mysql mechanism.